# PHP will not execute bash in Ubuntu server

Tags: php, html, bash, moodle

1. I am trying to use an html form action pointed to a PHP file in order to execute a .sh script in the background in Ubuntu server.
2. Click here (moodle) > php executes bash and redirects the web page > script runs and starts a headless vm. 
   php file is saved to /var/www/html/moodle 
   script is saved to /etc/init.d
   html code is obviously embedded in the site

   ```
   <form action="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/moodle/scriptname.php">
   <input type="submit" value="Button name">
   </form>
   ```

php configuration

```
    <?php
    putenv("PATH=/etc/init.d/:" .$_ENV["PATH"]."");
    $output = "<pre>".shell_exec("scriptname.sh")."</pre>";
    echo $output;
  header('Location:http://XXX.XXX.X.XX/moodle/mod/page/view.phpid=133&forceview=1');
    ?>
```

Script

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/StartVM
#
#Edit these variables!
VMUSER=myusername
VMNAME="nameofvm"
echo "Starting VirtualBox VM..."
sudo -H -b -u $VMUSER /usr/bin/VBoxVRDP -s "$VMNAME"
exit 1
;;
esac
exit 0
```

I cant figure out why the this wont work. The script produces results when ran in terminal. The html code redirect the web page according to the php file, but the script will not execute when clicking the button in moodle.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks
MAC

Comment: `myusername` should be `$USER` and if its `www-data` then sudo wont work until you add a line to sudoers

Comment: what would the line look like in sudoers?

Comment: `www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/VBoxVRDP`

Comment: Ive done both of those and no luck.

Comment: Anything in the error_log?  Put your `LogLevel Debug` and run again.

Comment: Wed Aug 22 18:11:55.406839 2018] [:error] [pid 5064] [client XXX.XXX.X.X:XXXXX] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: PATH in /var/www/html/moodle/custom.php on line 2, referer: http://XXX.XXX.X.XX/moodle/mod/page/view.php?id=132
/etc/init.d//scriptname.sh: 10: /etc/init.d//scriptname.sh: sudo: not found

Answer (score 0):

In your script, use the full path for sudo (*/usr/bin/sudo*) and modify your sudoers file if needed (Pointed out in the comments by **[Lawrence Cherone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661872/lawrence-cherone)**).